# R functions using data.frame$column not working

Tags: r, function, names

## The two following functions don't work at the moment, but do work when I write them out in full - not sure why. Any suggestions for fixes would be great.

```
change_specific_column_name <- function(data.frame,old_column_name,new_column_name){
  names(data.frame)[names(data.frame) == old_column_name] <- new_column_name
}

change_specific_observations_name <- function(data.frame, column_name, old_obseration, new_observation){
   data.frame$column_name[which(data.frame$column_name == old_obseration)] <- new_observation
}

test_frame <- data.frame(Does=1,This=2,Work=3)

change_specific_column_name(test_frame,"Work","Happen") # this doesn't change the name of the column

names(test_frame)[names(test_frame) == "Work"] <- "Happen" # writing out the function does change the name
```

Comment: Add a ```return(data.frame)``` at the end of your function call. Also dont call variables like base r functions/classes, such as ```data.frame```.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exact, you can think of the function's argument as passed-by-value, so it's perspicuous that changes made to the function's formal parameter don't impact the actual argument.

> Any suggestions for fixes would be great.

If you really want a function to modify its argument, you could use a technique described e. g. under [Call by reference in R](https://ctszkin.com/2011/09/11/call-by-reference-in-r/); essentially just wrap your assignment in `eval.parent(substitute(…))`.

```
change_specific_column_name <- function(data.frame, old_column_name, new_column_name)
 eval.parent(substitute(names(data.frame)[names(data.frame) == old_column_name] <- new_column_name))
```